# providing values to Crypto-js

Tags: angularjs, cryptojs

I've got CyryptoJs working (as a service), but I don't think I'm observing best practices with it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as CryptoJS from "crypto-js";

@Injectable()
export class EncryptionService {

    constructor() {
    }

    secretKey: string = "fnord";

    encrypt(jsonObj) {
        return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(jsonObj), this.secretKey);
    }

    decrypt(data) {
        if (data !==null && data.length > 0) {
            var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data.toString(), this.secretKey);
            return bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

**secretKey** should probably not be exposed like that. What would be a smart way to deliver that value?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to protect from whom? Doing encryption just to say that you're doing encryption is a bad idea, because it doesn't have to provide any meaningful security (which is what you're after presumably).

Comment: If you're using only symmetric encryption you need the exact same key at the server and the client. If you send the encryption key from the server to the client or the other way around you need to encrypt your symmetric encryption key. The easiest way to do this would be to use TLS. If you use TLS, then the data as well as key are encrypted, so you don't need to encrypt it yourself. This doesn't provide any security, just a little bit of obfuscation. You should read: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few security issues.

1. The encryption key needs to be unique for each user.
2. Use a full length key: 128, 192 or 256 bits for AES.
3. It is best to use a full length encryption key of random bytes obtained from a CSPRNG (Cryptographically Secure Random Number Generator).
4. Using a string for the key, especially a short one is not secure. If you need the user to enter a password use a key derivation function such as PBKDF2 (Password Based Key Derivation Function 2) function to derive a secure encryption key.
5. There needs to an IV (Initialization Vector) supplied and it needs to be a random byte array from a CSPRNG unique for each encryption. Just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use during decryption, it does not need to be secret.
6. It is best to fully specify all encryptions parameters such as mode and padding for interoperability.
7. If there is the possibility of entering an incorrect key or an attacker replacing a file add encryption authentication.
8. Add a version indicator to the encrypted data so changes can be made in the future if necessary.
9. Finally, how are you going to store the encryption key, there is no easy answer to that.

Comment: "...how are you going to store..." Presumably, the key will be delivered via back-end magic.

Comment: That means the key will be sent to the user and they key will not be provided by the user? Will the user be allowed to change it? Will the user enter the key as text or just saved somehow on their device and they will never see?