# localStorage as a service

Tags: angular, local-storage

Using angular 2. I am implementing a local storage service (with encryption). Currently, it's just my one module that's using it but I want to ensure it's reusable.

This is my page's .ts:

I'm providing a storage prefix. I'm assuming it should have an indication of what app it's associated with, so it's pre-prefixed with **myApp-**, followed by a prefix that would be unique to this module (**Frequentclients**).

```
export class SwitchClientComponent implements OnInit {

    storagePrefix = 'myApp-Frequentclients';

    getFrequentClients() {
        return this.encryptionService.getLocalStorage(this.storagePrefix);
    };
}
```

My encrypted storage service:

```
import * as CryptoJS from "crypto-js";

@Injectable()
export class EncryptionService {

    constructor() {
    }

    secretKey: string = "fnord";

    setLocalStorage(storagePrefix: string, jsonObj) {
        localStorage.setItem(storagePrefix, this.encrypt(jsonObj));
    }

getLocalStorage(storagePrefix: string) {
    var recentClients = [],
        data: string = localStorage.getItem(storagePrefix);

    if (data !== null && data.length > 0) {
        data = this.decrypt(data);
        if (data !== null && data.length > 0) {
            recentClients = JSON.parse(data) || [];
        }
    }
    return recentClients;
}

encrypt(jsonObj) {
    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(jsonObj), this.secretKey);
}

decrypt(data) {
    if (data !== null && data.length > 0) {
        var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data.toString(), this.secretKey);
        return bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

If every module that used local storage just used the same prefix, they'd clobber each other, right?

So each use will have it's own, thus:

```
myApp-DavesModuleData : [{data:'foo'}]
myApp-OtherModuleData : [{data:'bar'}]
```

Or, should I eschew littering the user's storage with a zillion local storage files, and just use one?

```
myApp : [{DavesModule:{data:'foo'}},{OtherModule:{data:'bar'}}]
```

Then I'd have to read the entire thing every time local storage is read and then parse it to find the section I'm looking for - AND write it all back again.

(That means, if any module messes up its data, it potentially brings every other use of the local storage to a screeching halt - including loss-of-stored-data).

BTW, I'm using angular 2 native local storage. Now that I'm encountering these challenges, I'm beginning to wonder if perhaps someone has already written a plugin that does sophisticated local storage management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a clear question here but i'll try to guess what is the answer that you want :)

Yes it is much better to reduce the amount of data that you will need to read from the localStorage by having different "modules" using different entries in the LS. For three main reasons:

1. Reading the local storage is a syncronous operation so it will block your code execution until is not finished
2. Reading/writing the local storage is one of the slower operations you can do in javascript.
3. Saving/retrieving data from the localstorage requires that you stringify/parse those data which is another one of the slower operations you can do in javascript.

I would tell you to read [this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/03/there-is-no-simple-solution-for-local-storage/) and then [this article](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/04/25/the-performance-of-localstorage-revisited/) about up to date localStorage performances.

Also note there are no "localStorage files" there's only one object in the browser so you can create as many entries as you want without performance loss, actually all the opposite.

As you said yes, if you store everything into one entry a single bad formatted data can make all the others objects unreacheable.

Comment: This answer totally misses the security errors in the encryption.

Comment: I really cannot find the question about security errors, can you point it out for me please?

Comment: I'm not compaining about the answer, just noting that there are also security errors i the OP's example code.

Comment: Encryption handled in a separate thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973478/providing-values-to-crypto-js
 - or are there other issues?

Comment: "...better to reduce the amount of data..." So my method is sound? Have each module provide its own prefix?

Comment: As i said i think so, it's the way i would go for anyway. Unless someone else can provide arguments in favour of the other way; i cannot see any.